# Change Haystack facet default limit using Solr

Tags: python, django, solr, django-haystack

As the [documentation](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/v2.4.1/faceting.html#configuring-facet-behaviour) states, the default limit for facets is set to 100 when using Solr. It can be set for each call:

```
sqs = SearchQuerySet().facet('field', limit=-1)  # default limit: 100
```

This is inconvenient for my current project, as there may be a lot of facets that exceed this limit. Is there a way to set the default limit to something else? Additionally, is there a reason the limit should not be deactivated (set to a negative number)?